# SSAS - cube DSN connectivity

Tags: windows, ssas, dsn, ssas-2012

I'm trying to pass Microsoft Platform Ready SQL Server 2012 - Silver BI tests.

One of the [requirements](http://www.microsoftplatformready.com/us/dashboard.aspx) is:

> Data Usage: Data Connectivity
>
> Cube must have a valid DSN Connectivity for pulling data from different data sources.

Does anyone know how to create a valid system DSN to a Analysis Services 2012 cube (on Windows 7 or higher)?

*Note: Administrative Tools -> Data Sources (ODBC) does not work since no ODBC driver for SSAS shows up in that list.*

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The way to overcome this is by having a SQL linked server in the middle.
So, the SSAS connects to a SQL server and the SQL server connects to the ODBC connection by using a linked server object.

This is no staging, the SQL server works like a tunnel, because you use OpenQuery from your SSAS data source view

Comment: I would have never in a million years thought of doing that.

In any case, the test connection to the linked server failed.

(Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "LSERVER".
OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "LSERVER" returned message "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified". (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 7303)

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.50.4302&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=7303&LinkId=20476

Comment: that error shows up because of the provider name, try creating the linked server with this query:

EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver  
@server = N'HiveCloud', @srvproduct=N'HIVE', 
@provider=N'MSDASQL', @datasrc=N'CI_Hive2',
@provstr=N'Provider=MSDASQL.1;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=UserX; Password=YYY';

The parameter
@datasrc=N'CI_Hive2'
is the name of your DSN on the ODBC connection. Make sure to create it in the System tab (server)

the parameter
@srvproduct=N'HIVE'
is your data provider

Set a user name and password to access the SQL server from your SSAS

Comment: Try first running the open queries from the sql management studio connected to the SQL server. in this way you know if your linked server and ODBC connection are working

Comment: Thanks for the example, it helped me figure out what I was doing wrong: the DSN was not defined on the right server (in this case I had 3 servers involved). Anyway, even if I can make a successful openquery now, I still cannot figure out how to include a DSN reference in my cube. I created a named openquery on my dataview, created a dimension from that result, and then a measure. **The test still fails**. I am afraid that what this test wants is that one of my cube's main data sources (not the dataview) be directly connected to that DSN. Seems logical but I just can't find a way to do that.

Comment: In your SSAS datasource you choose the SQL server name. For example, your DSN name is conn_a and your server name is server_a.  So your server_a has a linked server using conn_a, and in your ssas datasource you select the sql server provider and choose your server _a.  You can use the OpenQuery from the datasource view.

Comment: The sql server is the one using the DSN.

Comment: remember to use the login to connect to the linked server.

Comment: In the query you don't use the DSN, you use the linked server alias you have defined. In my example above the name is HiveCloud